# Feynman Lectures, Chapter 4, Fig 4-3

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy

[From the Feynman lectures Chapter 4, Fig 4-3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html)

"We lifted the one-pound weight only three feet and we lowered W pounds by five feet. Therefore W=3/5 of a pound."

If there is a change of 3ft in height for 1lbs, and the weight on the other side of the pulley -- W -- had a change of 5ft in height, shouldn't we deduce that W is 5/3 of a pound rather than 3/5?

Answer (score 0):

Feynman's answer is correct. This is homework-style question so I won't give a full answer, but if you calculate the work done on the known mass and equate this to the work done by the unknown mass you should be able to see this:

$$m_1 g d_1 = m_2 g d_2,$$

Where $d_1$ refers to the distance moved by mass $m_1$ and similar for $d_2$; $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.